# How do I declare an array of strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string

In C++ how can I declare an array of strings?  I tried to declare it as an array of `char` but that was not correct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
#include <string>

std::string my_strings[100];
```

That is C++, using the STL. In C, you would do it like this:

```
char * my_strings[100];
```

This reads as "my strings is an array of 100 pointer to char", and the latter is how strings are represented in C.

Answer (score 13):

I would rather recommend using a vector of strings in almost every case:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::string> strings;
```

Answer (score 0):

Conventional single string:

```
char foo[100] // foo is a 100 character string
```

What you need is probably:

```
char foobar[100][100] // foobar is a 100 member array of 100 character strings
```